# tips for animating d3.js shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js

You can see a working example of where I am with [this](http://www.d3geometry.com/sine2)

How can I make this less jerky?

The code works like this:

I have this method that calls itself via requestAnimationFrame

```
  animateCircle(state, direction) {
    this.drawSineGraph(state, direction);

    requestAnimationFrame(this.animateCircle.bind(this, state, direction));
  }
```

This in turn calls a `drawSineGraph` function:

```
  drawSineGraph(state, direction) {
    d3.select('.sine-curve').remove();

    const increase = 54 / 1000;

    state.sineIncrease = state.sineIncrease || 0;

    state.sineIncrease += increase;

    const sineData = d3.range(0, state.sineIncrease)
            .map(x => x * 10 / 85)
            .map((x) => {
              return {x: x, y: Math.sin(x)};
            });

    state.nextCoord = {x: state.xScale(_.last(sineData).x), y: state.yScale(Math.sin(_.last(sineData).y) + 1)};

    const sine = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('monotone')
            .x( (d) => {return state.xScale(d.x);})
            .y( (d) => {return state.yScale(d.y + 1);});

    state.xAxisGroup.append('path')
      .datum(sineData)
      .attr('class', 'sine-curve')
      .attr('d', sine);
  }
```

It increases a counter and draws the sine wave up to that point but the effect is very jerky.

How can I achieve a smooth movement as the sine wave expands?

Comment: Create one path, animate it with `stroke-dash`:  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the generate code, you recreate over and over again every curve segment. Overlapping more than 100 curves. You must add a segment at the end of the previous segment. The problems its:

```
 animateCircle(state, direction) {
    this.drawSineGraph(state, direction); // <--recreate the curve from the origin

    requestAnimationFrame(this.animateCircle.bind(this, state, direction)); 
  }
```

Comment: You're doing the same and your script never end. It continously add paths to svg, at some it crash due a lack of memory. Could you make it in a separate file just the graphic, without the react framework?

Comment: Have you refreshed the page?  I am just adding the data each time.  It works well.  Do a hard refresh on the page, here is the source https://github.com/dagda1/d3-geometry/blob/master/client/app/components/sine2.js#L45

Comment: Oooh yeeah much way better and mesmerize. That's beautiful ;)